# How to call a method and use it's return value as an another method parameter?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int theMethod(){
    return 3;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.theOutput);
    textView.setText(theMethod());
}
```

}

I have tried this. To write out the return value of theMethod to the screen with setText.

The result is the app just stopping when I try to start.

How could I do that? Thanks.

edit:
Thank you guys. Now it works. Luv ya all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(theMethod()));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have look in the documentation of TextView, you can see that setText(int) actually expects a resource id: (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int))

So you have to turn your int to a CharSequence, you could simply do

```
textView.setText(theMethod()+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

textview.setText(""+theMethod());

And post your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there are two `setText()` methods on `TextView`.

The first one is `setText(int param)` which you are using, and expects a **string resource ID**, like `R.string.some_text`.

What you intended to use was `setText(String param)` which displays the `String` in the `TextView`. To fix this, make your method return a String instead, like this:

```
public String theMethod(){
    return String.valueOf(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is when ever you try to pass int value to the `TextView`'s `setText()` method it tries to find a string resource associated with the integer you passed, thats why you are program is crashing.

try to set it as below

```
textview.setText(String.valueOf(theMethod()));
```

and then you will not get `ResourceNotFoundException`